# Web Part Resources e.g. Images and Scripts

Tags: web-part, sharepoint-foundation, visual-studio, visual-web-part

What is the best practice for including resources such as Images / Stylesheets / Scripts in a custom visual web part (built with Visual Studio)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the LAYOUTS mapped folder that puts them in /_layouts on the server.  Use a subfolder in the layouts folder that is unique to your project so that there are not conflicts with other solutions.